# Adding const char* to string_view

Tags: c++, string, memory, string-view

I have a `string_view`:

```
std::string_view view;
```

How can I append something like a const char* to it? For example:

```
std::string_view view = "hello";
view += " world"; // Doesn't work
```

Also, how can I create a `string_view` with a specified size?
Like for example:

```
std::string_view view(100); // Creates a string_view with an initial size of 100 bytes
```

Comment: `string_view` is just a view. i.e. the actual object is somewhere else. So you can only 'view' using `string_view`. You cannot append and cannot set the size.

Comment: So what's the point of std::string_view if it is just like a char*?

Comment: It is like a char* with length. It can be used like a regular container and it is easy to pass around functions (takes one parameter instead of two i.e (char*, int))

Comment: Is that it though?

Comment: `string_view` is designed to be usable in many places where a `std::string` can be used, but without needing to copy any data around. It is iteratable, so it can be used with other containers and algorithms that take input iterators.  Sub-views can be easily created within a `string_view` without copying any data.  It is just easier to work with than a raw `char*`+`int` pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string_view` is a *read-only* view into an existing `char[]` buffer stored elsewhere in memory, or to `char`s that are accessible by a range of iterators.  You can't add new data to a `std::string_view`.

For what you are attempting, you need to use `std::string` instead, eg:

```cpp
std::string s = "hello";
s += " world";
```

```cpp
std::string s(100, '\0');
```

Comment: So what's the point of `std::string_view` if it is just like a char*?

Comment: `string_view` provide some features/safeties over using a raw pointer.

Comment: @ManUser123 Its about the size() parameter. std::string has a disadvantage that it owns the buffer, but an advantage that it knows the size(). string_view remedies this by letting the user supply the buffer while still keeping fast size() lookups.

Comment: @Mikhail it is not just about `size()`. `string_view` offers other useful features, too. Searches, comparisons, sub-string extractions without needing to allocate new `string` copies, etc